# jquery ajax never calls browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm finding that my ajax method is never actually getting called.  I'm using this code:

```
$("#client").change(function(e) {   
    var url = 'https://...../clientToStations.php';
    var data = 'ident=' + $("option:selected", this).val()

    alert("curl -X POST -d " + data + ' ' + url);

    $.ajax({
        type: POST,
        url: url,
        data: data,
    }).done(function(html) {
        alert('Done');
        $("#station").html(html).removeAttr('disabled');
    }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        alert('fail');
    }).always(function () {
        alert('always');
    });
});
```

I do see the alert at the point I'd expect to.  If I copy/paste the curl command into my terminal I get back the exact data I'd expect.  However, none of the done/fail/always methods are getting hit here.

I then edited the clientToStations.php to do an error_log() to just say it's called.  When the ajax gets "run", that message never shows up in my apache error log.  It does show up properly when I run the curl command manually.  No other errors are appearing in the log.

Comment: try like this..$("#client").on('change',function(){

Comment: The change method is getting called just fine.  It's the ajax method that isn't being called.

Comment: POST in ajax should be in inverted commas..like this 'POST'

Comment: That makes no difference.  I've tried it without anything, like Dreamweaver autocompletes, in single quotes and in double-quotes

Comment: i was able to get it working by adding the 'POST'. i got the fail/always alert boxes.

Comment: Check the url? And try to print out the response text and status code in the fail section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being not using the done/fail/always, and going back to the supposedly older 'success' element inside the ajax call itself.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://..../clientToStations.php',
        data: {
            ident: $("option:selected", this).val()
        },
        success: function(html) {
            ....
        }
    });
```

I also changed the 'data' param to be an object instead of a built up string, but that wasn't related to the actual issue.